# Inkscape: Caps on lines are always black

Tags: vector, inkscape

If I use a cap on a line, usually so I can make an arrow, it is always black despite the stroke color. Is this a bug or am I not understanding something?

[image: two arrows. the second is on a darker background and its arrow tip is the wrong color]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Inkscape Wiki:](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/FAQ#How_do_I_change_the_color_of_markers_.28e.g._arrow_ends.29.3F)

> By default, markers are black. You can change their color to match the color of the stroke of the object they are applied to by enabling an effect: Extensions > Modify Path > Color Markers to Match Stroke.

You will have to apply this **after** you had drawn the line and defined the marker.

[image]

For a text based approach we may also edit the resulting .SVG file for a given marker to edit the path style as follows:

```
<marker
...
  <path
     ...
     style="fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:<color>;fill:<color>"
     ... />
....
</marker>
```

Replace `<color>` with the desired marker color in 6 digit RGB hexadecimal notation (eg. #ff0000 for red).

Comment: I see... Since I am on Mac OS, I can't use this feature because it requires lxml. >:/

Comment: Now that I'm looking at the SVG spec ( http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/painting.html#Markers ) can you tell me if you are able to have two different colored lines each with their own color-matched cap? From what I'm seeing, caps never inherit the colors of the lines that use them. This is SVG's fault, not Inkscape's.

Comment: See edit for SVG representation of marker style. Markers are independent of lines, they can have any color for stroke or fill.

Comment: I understand, but I wish that it wasn't true. I'd like to recycle caps on many lines where each line can have its own color (and a cap that matches) I'm still investigating if there's a workaround.

Comment: Cant test this here atm but the script tool I mentioned above *Color Markes to Match Stroke* should work on all selected strokes in one go.