# How does one extend arrows in SVG?

Tags: inkscape, svg, illustration

I would like to be able to **lengthen arrows** between cells in this

without changing their

- direction
- colour
- width
- dimensions of their heads

(Just adding to the length of the arrows)

[image]

[Source](http://health-and-medicine.wikia.com/wiki/File:Haematopoiesis_diagram.svg)

How would I achieve this in **Inkscape**?

Comment: No time to answer now. In Inkscape you can do it with the [node editor](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Paths-Editing.html). To change the head you must use he [xml editor](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/XML.html). See [here](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/XML-Examples.html), [here](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Attributes-Stroke.html#Attributes-Stroke-Markers). [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/marker-element.html), and the  [reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/painting.html#Markers).

Comment: Moving nodes with Ctrl+Alt can be useful: it conserves the direction as well as other properties.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Increase stroke size of an arrow, while keeping the arrowhead unchanged](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/101161/increase-stroke-size-of-an-arrow-while-keeping-the-arrowhead-unchanged)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Edit strokes in path edit mode

It is easy in Inkscape to change the length of a stroke in *edit path* mode ([image]) which will leave stroke properties including markers untouched:

[image]

This will only work on single strokes with predefined markers. This is not the case in the example SVG we have in the question.

#### Move marker objects with stroke

After ungrouping the objects we can see that strokes in the diagram are represented as multi-line objects. End markers are separate objects (triangles):

[image]

If we now change the stroke length by dragging the node of the stroke we can see that the end marker triangle will remain in place:

[image]

We will, after changing a stroke length, have to **move the triangle** to the appropriate position too. To change the triangle geometry we can move its path handles.

#### Convert objects to single strokes

Alternatively we can of course convert the line object to single strokes by selecting the start and end node of a line to then **break apart** the path  (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>).

Then we are able to adjust the stroke length, and add a stroke end marker property (here I chose *TriangleOutM*, choose any other marker to alter its shape):

[image]

For changing stroke **and** marker color see: [Inkscape: Caps on lines are always black](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/21692/inkscape-caps-on-lines-are-always-black)